# Переход по прямой ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Для динамической подгрузки контента есть ajax запрос

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link == 'index.html' {
          $('#content').prev('.slider').show();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: link,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#spinner').show();
            },
            success: function(mes){
                $('#content').prev('.slider').hide();
                $('#content').html(mes);
                reinitOpacity();
                $(window).scroll();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#spinner').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

И все работает хорошо. Но допустим мы переходим по прямой ссылке и получаем непосредственно страницу. Но на этой странице только информация которую нужно подгрузить, ни скриптов ни стилей ничего. Как можно сделать чтобы данная страница подгружалась в так скажем шаблон и уже грузилась из него.

Comment: Ну так вы на той стороне проверку делайте: если ajax, отдаете как ajax, если просто get - отдаете нормальную страницу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На серверной стороне вы можете отдавать либо всю страницу целиком (для обычных запросов), либо только блок, обновляемый через AJAX (для AJAX запросов). В большинстве фреймворков и библиотек, предоставляющих методы для отправки AJAX запросов, используется заголовок `X-Requested-With` со значением `XMLHTTPRequest`. jQuery не является исключением.

А вот пример кода на PHP, который позволит отличить обычный запрос от AJAX запроса:

```
$is_ajax = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

if ($is_ajax) {
    // Это AJAX запрос. Отдаем только часть страницы
    // ...
} else {
    // Это обычный запрос. Отдаем страницу целиком
    // ...
}
```

Аналогичный подход используется, например, в [Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1762).

Comment: мне не нужно определять это ajax или обычный запрос. Или вы предлагаете иметь полные страницы, но исходя из условия выбирать часть страницы или всю целиком грузить?

Comment: Немного не понял вопрос в части "_иметь полные страницы_". Я предлагаю, отдавать скриптом целую страницу (со всей разметкой, подключением стилей и прочим) для нормальных запросов и только часть страницы для AJAX запросов.

Comment: да это я и имел ввиду. Т.е. я должен иметь целые страницы и отдавать результат исходя из запроса. Тогда придется все делать через $.load если вытаскивать кусок из страницы.

Comment: А причем тут `$.load`? Если я правильно вижу проблему, то вам не нужно будет менять клиентский код - AJAX запросы будут работать так как есть сейчас, а отдача целых страниц будет полностью реализована на сервере.

Comment: можно тогда поподробнее, а то не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать, или хотя бы подскажите где можно посмотреть информацию как это делается

Comment: Фактически ваша задача сводится к редактированию серверного кода, и выбору правильного ответа для правильного запроса. Как сделать этот выбор я уже показал. А остальное зависит исключительно от того, как контент генерируется у вас на сервере.

Comment: как сделать выбор я понял, спасибо. Но вот проблема как раз в том, что ума не приложу как заставить сервер отдавать мне страницу целиком или часть без шапки, стилей, скриптов и т. д.

Comment: Откройте новый вопрос и изложите суть проблемы там.

Answer (score 2):

*Сразу оговорюсь, ответ может быть гораздо шире заданного вопроса и вашей проблемы.*

## Варианты:

### 1. Разделите на разные форматы

Если у вас есть программируемая серверная часть, разбейте эти варианты ответа на два разных формата. Запрос с `Accept: text/html` обрабатывайте, как запрос на полноценную страницу.

В этом есть смысл ещё и потому, что кусок HTML редко является корректным HTML-документом: в нём нет аннотации с версией разметки (`doctype`), нет корневого тега (`<html>`). Отвечать на запрос HTML-документа обрубком не очень правильно.

А вот второй формат (для [параметра `accepts` в jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)) нужно выбирать, и выбор зависит от ваших требований:

1. Если не знаете, с чего начать, можете взять JSON: в jQuery есть [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), а на сервере оформите ваш кусочек разметки в корректный JSON.

   - Когда-нибудь потом можете избавиться от разметки и возвращать "чистые данные", форматируя их в HTML клиентом — это если вы захотите для этой же серверной части сделать мобильное приложение, где проще разобрать JSON и рассовать данные по виджетам, чем разбирать присланный кусочек HTML на ещё более мелкие кусочки.
2. Если JSON по этому адресу уже делает что-то другое (вдруг вы делаете нормальный такой многоформатный API), можете взять `text/plain`, обычный текст. Ему, например, не требуется экранирование, и всяческие сжимающие/оптимизирующие шлюзы вряд ли осмелятся его трогать. Впрочем, если JSON по этому адресу уже что-то возвращает, задумайтесь — может, там уже есть всё необходимое?

   Отмечу также, что это уровень довольно грязных хаков — вы рискуете получить очень вёселое и неожиданное поведение в клиентах, которые по умолчанию имеют в `Accept` тип `text/plain`. Поэтому посмотрите и другие решения.
3. Если даже `text/plain` занят, смотрите другие варианты.

### 2. Добавьте параметр для возврата кусочка страницы

У `jQuery.ajax` в параметре `data` укажите что-то, что можете поймать сервером для возврата неполного ответа, например `"partial": "true"`. Когда делаете запрос из JS, добавляйте этот параметр, а на сервере реагируйте на него и не заворачивайте ответ в шаблон.

Так прямую ссылку с параметром пользователь сможет получить разве что специально, посмотрев на фактические запросы инструментами разработчика, а "простой пользователь" получит ссылку без параметра (скопировав адрес ссылки, например), по которой сервер должен вернуть полный запрос.

### 3. Размещайте полноценные страницы

...при AJAX-запросе вырезайте только ту часть, которая вам нужна. JS будет существенно сложнее, зато по прямой ссылке вы всегда будете получать CSS/JS, а усилий со стороны серверной части вообще не потребуется (работает даже для статики).

Такой подход использует [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) и считается удобным из-за отсутствия процесса настройки (запрашивается всё ещё `text/html`), что быстро рушится, как только появляется необходимость выполнять JS после загрузки (нужно цепляться не к событиям документа, а к событиям Turbolinks).

Comment: Вы ведь знаете, что HTTP заголовок `Accept` может содержать несколько mime-типов? Если следовать пункту 1 вашего ответа, что должен отдавать сервер, если браузер передаст `Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html`?

Comment: Да, знаю, и это проблема -- браузеры по умолчанию передают целую пачку форматов (мой Firefox DE шлёт `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`), контроль над ними есть только в запросах из JS. Поэтому `text/plain` использовать для частичных ответов несколько рискованно. Поэтому и указан он, как крайняя мера. Я пока не встречал ни одного случая, когда нельзя было бы использовать JSON :)

Comment: Вообще заголовок `Accept` (как и `Content-type`) должны точно определять тип содержимого. Поэтому, п.1 вашего ответа сводится к "_используйте `Accept: application/json`_", что ведет к дополнительному оверхеду как на сервере так и на клиенте.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev для заголовка `Accept` это неправда, иначе не было бы возможности указывать там несколько значений. Оверхед для разбора этого JSON на фоне вставки в страницу (где строка ещё будет разобрана, как разметка) невелик. На сервере -- зависит от реализации.

Comment: да, действительно, про `Accept` погорячился. А что касается JSON - то это ненужное усложнение системы на пустом месте. Передавайте на сервер _любой другой_ загловок, по которому можно отличить AJAX запрос от обычного и не нужно никакой магии с `Accept`. Многие фреймворки используют `X-Requested-With`...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev хороший вариант. В сущности то же, что и п. 2, просто указывается не в параметрах запроса, а HTTP-заголовком.